# Побайтовое чтение COM порта

Tags: c++

Обычно из COM порта читают передавая в функцию чтения указатель на буфер и сколько байтов прочитать. Как правило, буфер большой и длина соответственная. Вопрос следующий, а если я хочу читать побайтово, то есть за одно чтение читать из порта один байт? Это приведет к потере данных?

Comment: А _как_ вы читаете данные из порта? В самом C++ нету встроенных средств доступа к аппаратуре, вы явно используете какую-то библиотеку.

Comment: Не приведет, пока не переполнится буфер где-то в потрохах реализации COM-порта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данные, которые приходят на COM порт буферизуются как в железе, так и внутри операционной системы (если она есть). Так или иначе, данные кладутся в некоторый буфер. Если их оттуда не читать, то буфер закончится, и данные будут либо перезаписываться, либо отбрасываться (зависит от его настроек в железе/ОС).

Однако современные компьютеры (и микроконтроллеры тоже) работают на частотах значительно превышающих максимальную скорость работы COM порта, по этому если читать по одному байту в цикле - то он никогда не успеет переполниться.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А как реализовано чтение из буфера COM порта? Скажем пришло n байт на порт, я прочел 1 байт. Этот байт данных удаляется из буфера? Размер данных в буфере будет равен n-1?